# Github credential management

Tags: git, github

I have a set of servers. In each of the server, I download code from `Github` and run different `scripts`.

I don't want to put my `Github` ssh key in all those machines.

What could be a better alternative?

So far, I came up with the following options:

- create a new Github read-only user and use that user from these machine
- use a personal access token

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Why do you have a problem putting the ssh keys on the servers that require secure access to your Github repository?

Comment: What's wrong with the two solutions you proposed?

Answer (score 2):

In order to access a private repository, you must have some sort of authentication.  GitHub provides three options for that: SSH keys on your personal account, tokens (usually personal access tokens) on your personal account, or SSH deploy keys.

If you only need access to a single repository, using one or multiple SSH deploy keys is a good strategy.  A deploy key can be restricted to being read-only (or read-write, if you prefer) and it's only for a single repository, so any compromise is restricted to the one repository.  You can use multiple keys, one per server, if you want increased security and ease of revocation.

You can also use an additional SSH key that's tied to your personal account for these servers (separate from your personal key).  However, that means that the account's repositories can be accessed (both read and write) with the key on the servers, which is less secure.

You can also use a personal access token (or multiple such tokens) to access the repositories over SSH, which also gives you access to multiple repositories, but also gives that token some access to the API.  That may be desirable or undesirable, depending on your security model.